# Enable/disable button template of gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

how to enable the delete button only if the user have modify the data in a gridview

```
<EditItemTemplate>
  <div class='actions'>
  <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text=" Update " ToolTip="Update Row" CommandName="Update" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text=" Cancel " ToolTip="Cancel Row" CausesValidation="false"  CommandName="Cancel" />
  </div>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use this code.
In Source File

```
 <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="true" HeaderText="Edit / Delete" ItemStyle-Width="8%"
                                        ShowDeleteButton="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
```

In Cs File

```
 protected void gvStatMeasures_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            gvStatMeasures.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            // Bind Grid View
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            fnMessage(true, ex.Message);
        }
    }

protected void gvStatMeasures_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        gvStatMeasures.EditIndex = -1;
        // Bind Grid View
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        fnMessage(true, ex.Message);
    }
}



  protected void gvStatMeasures_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {


            int iStaticTypeID = Int32.Parse(gvStatMeasures.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());  // this get Datakey value of GridView as PK or else where need to identify records.

            // Delete Code
            //Bind Grid
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            fnMessage(true, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Second Way,

Please add new button as Delete in your code as visible False and only visible when you click for edit.
So that time its visible true and you can add code in that also.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this answer to a related question will help: [Hide Repeater columns based on user privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949467/hide-repeater-columns-based-on-user-privileges/4949627#4949627)