# Hide Repeater columns based on user privileges

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, repeater

Can somebody explain to me how to hide a repeater column based on the user privileges.

Say I have:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server>
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table id="table_id">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Secret Info</th>
      <tr>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /></td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SecretInfo") %>' /></td>
      <tr>
  <ItemTemplate>
  <AlternatingItemTemplate>
      <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /></td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SecretInfo") %>' /></td>
      <tr>
  <AlternatingItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

How would I only display the 'Secret Info' column to logged on users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can render the `<td>` elements conditionally. This simplified example presumes you have a Page-level property that indicates whether or not the user is logged on (you'll want to do the same thing in the header template):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'  /></td>
            <% if (this.UserIsLoggedOn) { %>
            <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SecretInfo") %>' /></td>
            <% } %>
        <tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Useful technique, it worked for me once I elevated my local variable to be a *public* class attribute of my page class, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following:

```
<td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SecretInfo") %>' Visible='<%# IsUserLoggedOn() %>' /></td>
```

Where IsUserLoggedOn is some function that returns a boolean that is true if the user is logged on

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the column would still be visible? ie. There would be a blank column in the table?

Comment: you could add the same check to the th in the header for secret info.  I think theChrisKent has a better answer for you though

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `loginview` control which can display controls based on role (including anonymous vs authenticated). You can find a guide here: http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2010/07/28/role-based-authorization-using-loginview-control.aspx

So something like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server>
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table id="table_id">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <asp:LoginView ID="lvwHeader" runat="server">
          <LoggedInTemplate>
            <th>Secret Info</th>
          </LoggedInTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
      <tr>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /></td>
        <asp:LoginView ID="lvwItem" runat="server">
          <LoggedInTemplate>
            <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SecretInfo") %>' /></td>
          </LoggedInTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
      <tr>
  <ItemTemplate>
  <AlternatingItemTemplate>
      <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /></td>
        <asp:LoginView ID="lvwItem" runat="server">
          <LoggedInTemplate>
            <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SecretInfo") %>' /></td>
          </LoggedInTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
      <tr>
  <AlternatingItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I think this would mean I would need two repeaters? One for the anonymous and one for the public?

Comment: @Coder 2 see my updated answer, I've included a sample implementation

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer. Do you happen to know if there is a way to make a column work in the reverse way. ie. Visible for anonymous user and invisible for any logged in user?

Comment: No worries, I got it now AnonymousTemplate. Thanks!