# Hiding/Removing <th> from code behind

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table

In my code I'm retrieving user that is admin or user. On my table in aspx I have a "th" tag that I want to hide/remove if the user is not admin.

Here is my html code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <asp:Label ID="lblActionHeader" runat="server" Visible = '<%# UserIsAdmin() %>' >
            <th>Action</th>
         </asp:Label>
         <th>Name of Insured</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptrList" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptrList_ItemCommand">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <tr>
           <asp:Label ID="lblActionBody" runat="server" Visible = '<%# UserIsAdmin() %>' >
             <td>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit">                      
               </asp:LinkButton>
             </td>
           </asp:Label>
           <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' Enabled="false" CssClass="m-wrap small"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
   </tbody>

</table>
```

in my code - behind I have this function that getting the user if its admin or not.

```
 public bool UserIsAdmin()
    {
        bool bRet;
        bool.TryParse(Session["isAdmin"].ToString(), out bRet);
        return bRet;
    }
```

On the Repeater it works but on the header it doest work.

Is there any other way to hide a  tag

Comment: I got the answer from this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949467/hide-repeater-columns-based-on-user-privileges?rq=1

Comment: then please add your answer and tick it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide Repeater columns based on user privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949467/hide-repeater-columns-based-on-user-privileges)

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer from this link

[Hide Repeater columns based on user privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949467/hide-repeater-columns-based-on-user-privileges?rq=1)

Comment: You should write proper question before asking question in the question you asked that its works fine with repeater but not with header that's why I have given my solution for page load and still you down voted this

Answer (score 0):

In page_load event you need to check that and make label visible false.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       bool bRet;
       bool.TryParse(Session["isAdmin"].ToString(), out bRet);
       lblActionBody.Visible=bRet;
}
```

Comment: I think lblActionBody should be lblActionHeader as the questioner wants to hide the header rather than the body.